# How full is a gas cylinder?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, gas-laws

There are 7 different gas cylinders filled with:

- nitrogen
- oxygen
- air
- methane
- hydrogen sulfide
- carbon dioxide
- sulfur dioxide

How do I determine how much of the respective gases is left?

Nitrogen and oxygen are in a gaseous state, so I reckon a glance at a pressure indicator will do. Air? The same. How about the last four cylinders which are filled with liquids? They have their vapor pressure, but I am not sure that those pressures can be used to accurately calculate the volume of respective liquids. Should the weight of the cylinder be measured?

Comment: What is their normal pressures? Pressurise nearly any gas enough and it will liquify.  Most gas cylinders of those gases don't have liquid contents- it would be most inconvenient for users to have the liquid interfere with valves.

Comment: @user2617804 Try opening the valve of a CO2 cylinder standing upside down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct.

For the non-liquifying gases (room temperature is far above their critical temperature) knowing the pressure is enough, if you know the volume of your cylinders. (You need a better formula than $pV=nRT$ to calculate the amount of gas at those high pressures. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation, virial expansion, ...)

Actually the van der Waals equation is *not useful*, because, although it gives a good  idea *why* the ideal gas law breaks, it gives very wrong numbers esp. for high pressures. [BWR or BWRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%E2%80%93Webb%E2%80%93Rubin_equation) are supposed to work well, at the cost of using eight or eleven constants.

For those gases which are partially liquified ($\ce{CO2}$ at $57\ \mathrm{bar}$, $\ce{H2S}$ at $12\ \mathrm{bar}$, $\ce{SO2}$ at $3.5\ \mathrm{bar}$), you need to know the weight (and tare weight) of the cylinders, of course.

Comment: I suggest that if a gas cylinder doesn't have a tare weight on it, be wary of buying from that supplier again. Maybe the [discovery of PTFE](http://www.fluoroconsultants.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/royplunkettworld.pdf) is connected.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Karl's answer a bit, not only do you need a better [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) than $PV=nRT$ to accurately measure the contents, depending on the cylinder pressure several of the listed gases may require a correction for effects due to the [supercritical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid) phase change.

\begin{array}{c|cc}
\mathrm{Species} & T_c \left(^\circ\mathrm C\right) & P_c \left(\mathrm{psi}\right) \\
\hline
\ce{N2} & -147 & 493 \\
\ce{O2} & -118.6 & 731 \\
\ce{CH4} & -82.6 & 668.5 \\
\ce{H2S} & 100 & 1300 \\
\ce{CO2} & 31 & 1070 \\
\ce{SO2} & 157.2 & 1143 \\
\hline
\end{array}

*Data links* — [$\ce{N2}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7727379&Units=SI&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) – [$\ce{O2}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7782447&Units=SI&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) – [$\ce{CH4}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74828&Units=SI&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) – [$\ce{H2S}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7783064&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) – [$\ce{CO2}$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Units=SI&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) – $\ce{SO2}$ [$T_c$](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7446095&Units=SI&Mask=4#Thermo-Phase) [$P_c$](http://encyclopedia.airliquide.com/Encyclopedia.asp?GasID=27#GeneralData).

So, even for the gases well above their boiling points at room temperature ($\ce{N2}$, $\ce{O2}$, air, $\ce{CH4}$), if the cylinder pressure exceeds the respective critical pressure for that gas it will still be necessary to weigh the cylinders to get a highly accurate measure of the remaining contents, since supercritical phases generally have liquid-like densities.

Comment: This is a misconception. Unless you are really close to the liquid state, density of a gas (supercritical or not) increases largely linearly with pressure. There also is no phase transition between normal gas and supercritical.

Comment: @Karl Interesting! So, is it that this far above $T_c$ the density will be substantially that of an ideal gas?

Comment: No, but it will not be *very* far off. The density will always *approximately* double if you double the pressure... until the gas becomes incompressible. That would be the opposite of what you say.

Comment: @Karl But, regardless, the IGL will not be valid for accurate absolute calculations of the mass of the cylinder contents, correct?

Comment: Even vdW becomes rather inaccurate at 200 bar, i believe. For any actual technical application, this one would be right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%E2%80%93Webb%E2%80%93Rubin_equation

Comment: By way of comparison, at the typical state for a full gas cylinder ($p=200\ \mathrm{bar}$, $T=25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$), the values for the molar volume are $V_\mathrm m=0.1239\ \mathrm{l\ mol^{-1}}$ (ideal gas), $V_\mathrm m=0.1308\ \mathrm{l\ mol^{-1}}$ (nitrogen), $V_\mathrm m=0.1173\ \mathrm{l\ mol^{-1}}$ (oxygen), $V_\mathrm m=0.1277\ \mathrm{l\ mol^{-1}}$ (air), and $V_\mathrm m=0.1021\ \mathrm{l\ mol^{-1}}$ (methane).

Comment: @Loong Not that far from ideal behaviour. Interesting numbers, never looked at that. So oxygen has 280g /l compared to 1100 for the liquid, 156 compared to 420 for methane.